# How do I minimize code view in vim after switching to insert mode

Tags: vim, python-mode

An opened **`.py`** file in minimized view.

[image]

#### After navigating to a class and switching to **insert mode**

If I want to view the code details I just navigate to the method or class I want and switch to `insert` Mode as shown below.
[image]

How do I do I minimize back the code view? I am using vim's `Python-mode` plug in.

Comment: don't know the plugin, but this seems to be a folding issue, look at `:h folding`

Comment: Thanks I'll check also how do I remove the red vertical  line?

Comment: that's the `colorcolumn` have a lock at `:h colorcolumn`

Comment: Thank you I have checked it out and navigated to my `~/.vimrc` file then commented the line with:
`highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=red guibg=red`

Comment: actually i would use `set cc=0` which deactivates the colorcolumn completly. YOur solution just removes the color from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `za`, which folds/unfolds a fold.

Comment: No problem @philip. I believe that `:help z` will show some more examples too, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `z+<>` shortcuts:

- `z+o` to open a folding
- `z+c` to close a folding
- `z+O` to open all foldings [from current selection if I'm not wrong]
- `z+C` to close all foldings [from current selection if I'm not wrong]